# APCUPSD and "do_IRQ: 3.33 No irq handler for vector"

Tags: logs

Logs are filled with error:

```
Jul 21 17:56:36 servername kernel: [ 2883.646823] do_IRQ: 3.33 No irq handler for vector
```

Help!  What is this?

Its a brand new 18.04 server install on new hardware.  I installed APCUPSD via "apt-get -y install apcupsd" and the errors started during the installation.  2 or 3 reboots, the errors persisted.  Removed APCUPSD and the errors stopped.  Reinstalled, they come back.  Turning off the apcupsd service stops the errors.

All the search hits on this error seem to be for very old stuff, like Ubuntu 12 or 14.  I need to use APCUPSD.  What is going wrong here?

Comment: Have you done any edits to the /etc/apcupsd/apcupsd.conf file? Usually it just requires properly identifying the type of UPS and its connection method.

Comment: Yes, I set the .conf file to what I believe is correct, based on using apcupsd with other systems.

Comment: USB or serial port connection? What did you set the .conf for?

Comment: I gave the UPS a name, and set it for USB, and I think that's the only changes I made.

Comment: Tell me the UPSCABLE, UPSTYPE, DEVICE settings

Comment: `UPSCABLE usb
    UPSTYPE usb
    DEVICE /dev/ttyS0`

lsusb produces (among other things):

    `Bus 001 Device 018: ID 051d:0002 American Power Conversion Uninterruptible Power Supply`

Comment: comment out `#DEVICE /dev/ttyS0` and retry. Report back.

Comment: This appears to have fixed my problem.  Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

In `/etc/apcupsd/apcupsd.conf` there are at least three settings that are important for proper operation of apcupsd via USB. They are UPSCABLE, UPSTYPE, and DEVICE.

In your case, UPSCABLE, UPSTYPE, should be set to `usb`, and DEVICE should be set to `#DEVICE`.